# Add class with a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have this div

```
<div class="newDiv">
```

It is generating in loop, something like

```
<div class="newDiv">
     <div class = "innerDiv">
      SomeCode
     </div>
</div>
<div class="newDiv">
     <div class = "innerDiv">
      SomeCode
     </div>
</div>
<div class="newDiv">
     <div class = "innerDiv">
      SomeCode
     </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add another class "BrightDiv" with the div that generated at odd places like

with first and third div.

what should I do to add Class "BrightDiv" along with "newDiv" with every div at odd place?

Comment: Show the code you are using to generate the DIVs.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Comment: Just use a conditional like if (i % 2). Obviously i is a counter of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You can use `:odd` or `:even` to select odd / even elements, but it is depend on the `index` position and not natural number count. So In your case, you want first and third position `div` i.e. with index= 0 and 2 which is even by index position and hence use `:even`.

```
$('div.newDiv:even').addClass('BrightDiv');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dyjb8r9w/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to select only the odd indexed divs

```
$(".newDiv").filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() % 2 == 1;
}).addClass("BrightDiv");
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you a solution `$("div:even").addClass("BrightDiv");`

Answer (score 1):

Ways to achieve this:

**CSS:**

```
.newDiv:nth-child(odd) { /*CSS*/ }
```

or

```
.newDiv:nth-child(2n-1) { /*CSS*/ }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.newDiv:odd').addClass('BrightDiv');
```